# Ejected Expo, React Native, can't find libreactnativejni.so

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got an Ejected Expo project, that's getting the following error while trying to run on Android.

I'm aware there's lots of documentation on this issue but all seem focused on 64bit binaries being included. I've unzipped the APK that's generated and the lib folder only contains :

/x86
/armeabi-v7a

So if there is a 64Bit include, I cant see where it would be?

Any suggestions?

```
2019-06-02 17:32:27.725 6202-6280/com.projectName.dynamic E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so
2019-06-02 17:32:27.727 6202-6280/com.projectName.dynamic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.projectName.dynamic, PID: 6202
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:703)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:564)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:500)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:455)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:18)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:19)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:914)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```